# How mapped descendant class like a base class?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have project (dll) `P` with `Automapper` in references. This project contains source class and base destination class for mapping. Definitions:

```
public class Source
{
    public Source()
    {

    }

    // Properties ..
}

public class DestinationBase
{
    public DestinationBase()
    {

    }

    // Properties ..
}
```

Project `P` also contains static `Mapper` initializer (in static contructor), which map `Source` type to `DestinationBase` type.

```
public class DataMapping
{
    public static DataMapping()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Source, DestinationBase>();

            // Another mapping ..
        });
    }
}
```

In and only in `P` I do mapping between `Source` and `BaseDestination` class.

```
public DestinationBase Map(Source s)
{
    return Mapper.Map<DestinationBase>(s);
}
```

So far, so good. But i have another project(**s**), `Q` for example, which has `P` in references (can use classes from `P`, obviously). `Q` aslso contains `DestinationDerived` class which derived from `DestinationBase`.

```
public class DestinationDerived : DestinationBase
{
    public DestinationDerived()
    {

    }

    // Properties ..
}
```

I want use `DestinationDerived` the exactly same way like DestinationBase in mapping. I extended `Map` function for descendants, **but mapper throw cast exception** - from parent to descendant, of course (i registered parent, but i want descendant).

```
public T Map<T>(Source s) where T: DestinationBase
{
    return Mapper.Map<T>(s);
}
```

And my question: **how, in my case, change code or split/extend configuration for mapping descendant class like a base class** ie call `Map` for each derived class from `DestinationBase` like

```
var derived = Map<DestinationDerived>(new Source());
```

**NOTES:**
* It's possible change or split configuration
* It's impossible move classes or configuration
* I know about `Include` and `IncludeBase` but `P` doesn't know types from `Q` and I can't move *whole* mapper configuration to `Q` (because I have many projects at the same level like `Q` with derived classe).
* I want only one mapper.
* I need base configuration for `DestinationBase` extends for specific (derived) configuration for `DestinationDerived`.
* I know about double map possibility (`map(DestinationDerived <- map(DestinationBase) <- Source)`) with second mapper. I use it already, but I want only one mapping (performance).
* If you require some other information, tell me!

**Thank You!**

**UPDATE 1:**
I created small sample of my problem. I placed that [sample](https://github.com/honzakuzel1989/examples/tree/master/C%23/AutoMapperInheritance) on my github. If you want you can make clone my examples repository and work with real sample. Keep in mind, that 'inherited projects' can be more than one. Thank You  again!

Comment: is dependency injection an option for you? you could have some interface for mapper configuration, that is collected from all assemblies when your DI container is initialized, and then configures that one mapper with rules that come from different assemblies

Comment: Yes, I use DI. I will try DI container possibilities. Thanks.

Comment: What about mapping profiles? https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration#profile-instances. And as @DarkSquirrel42 mentioned, use dependency injection to add them all

Comment: I do not want add reference to AutoMapper into all project referenced `P`. Moreover, I have no control over DI contajner. I can use injected classes, create services and modules (dll), but that is all.